# Storing notes securely

Tags: security

I'm moving from macOS to elementary OS and so far I already have most of the tools I use covered. There are some things still missing though, and one of them is the place where I keep passwords and other data like bank account logins and such. In the macOS keychain, secure notes can be stored.

Is there a similar app available for elementary OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few password managers for linux. If you search on password in the App Center you'll see some good ones pop up. I use password gorilla myself. It's also cross platform (Mac and Win). As car as secure notes, what were you looking to have as far as features. There are a ton of web based ones. I use Google Keep, which can be used as a web app and act as a real application.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I was looking for `keychain` but couldn't find anything. While searching on `password` I found **Revelation Password Manager** to be very neat.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! And welcome to elementary!

Comment: In the end I went with Bitwarden and I'm still using it.